# Particular jpeg image does not preview in Nautilus and cannot be uploaded

Tags: jpeg, upload, nautilus

I have a group of .jpg images from the same source that all seem to behave fine: I can open/edit them with eog/Kolourpaint/GIMP, their thumbnails load correctly in Nautilus, etc.

However, when I try to upload these images (through a web browser onto Tumblr for instance), one (and only one) of these does not preview in the Nautilus file upload browser, and Tumblr returns an error when I try to upload this file.

What kinds of issues would cause an otherwise well-behaved jpeg image to not preview in the Nautilus file upload browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At sthysel's suggestion, I converted my corrupted jpeg into a png, which revealed the problem and also provided me with a functional png that could be uploaded in the jpeg's place.

```
$ convert bad.jpg okay.png
convert: Premature end of JPEG file `bad.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/EmitMessage/228.
convert: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment `bad.jpg' @ warning/jpeg.c/EmitMessage/228.
```

Taking a look inside the actual contents of bad.jpg, it was apparently missing the EOF bytes:

```
000d330: 8cbd e32f f164 95a4 4827 54e0 1264 8807  .../.d..H'T..d..                  
000d340: 8436 479f cd1e afa4 d9e3 0a              .6G........
```

So I padded the file with the necessary bytes, which also worked to fix the jpeg.

```
000d330: 8cbd e32f f164 95a4 4827 54e0 1264 8807  .../.d..H'T..d..
000d340: 8436 479f cd1e afa4 d9e3 3fff d90a       .6G.......?...
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question directly, but a recipe for dealing with "slightly corrupt" images is the convert flap...

```
$ convert broken.jp cbroken.png
$ convert cbroken.png good.jpg
```

I find that image manipulation tools have different tolerance levels for specification compliance. Convert is both very tolerant and compliant in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had considered using convert and it actually outputted some useful debug information.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that have caused compatibility issues for me in the past were:

- Previews saved in a jpeg - disable storing previews (if supported by
  software)
- CMYK images saved as jpeg - convert to RGB before saving or export a
  copy as RGB